# Python subprocess write new line to stdin until process ends

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I've created a subprocess using

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The command it calls will print various information, and then wait for a `\n` before printing more information. Eventually, the process will end when `\n` has been pressed enough times. I need to be able to programatically simulate the pressing of `\n` until the process ends, as well as capturing all output. I do not want the output to be printed to the Terminal. I would like it to be returned and set to a variable.

How would I do this?

Comment: Is the number of newlines necessary a constant? Or can it change between runs?

Comment: Using popen or popen2 is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module - it gives you a uniform interface and streams to read/write data from.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething er, the OP *is* using `subprocess`.

Comment: @Nathaniel also something else to check - does it actually do the newline prompting when called via `subprocess`, as opposed to you running it directly? A lot of "paged" command line programs don't actually use paging when called directly rather than from a terminal.

Comment: I'm not really sure yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have to write to `stdin` once, you could use

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(..., stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write('\n')
```

However, if you need to wait for a prompt or interact with the subprocess in a more complicated way, then use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).
(pexpect works with any POSIX system, or Windows with Cygwin.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this  way

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shlex
with open (filename, 'w') as fileHandle
proc = Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr  = PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate(input = '\n')
print out, err
```